# What is vmlinuz.efi.signed?

Tags: kernel, live-usb, uefi, secure-boot

Installation media for Ubuntu 12.10 [contain](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.list) a copy of the kernel named `vmlinuz.efi.signed`.

What is it for, and how is it made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For installation on EFI boot systems (most new systems), vmulinuz has to be signed by a private key. It was an issue that the open source community discussed with hardware vendors. If it says it is signed then this means that it was signed with some private key so that it could be installed in EFI mode on an EFI system.

Comment: To be more precise, the `vmlinuz.efi.signed` file is signed with Canonical's private key, which is also used to sign the version of GRUB that Ubuntu 12.10 uses. This key is recognized by the version of shim that Ubuntu 12.10 uses. This version of shim is in turn signed by one of Microsoft's keys, which Microsoft uses to sign third-party binaries. Thus, the chain of trust is that the firmware recognizes the Microsoft signature on shim, which launches GRUB using Canonical's signature, which launches the kernel using Canonical's signature.